# Получить дни месяца для текущей недели: почему не видит элемент в list

Tags: python, list, calendar

```
def get_week():
    date = datetime.today()
    year = date.strftime('%Y')
    # >>>2017
    month = date.strftime('%m')
    # >>>12        
    current_day = date.strftime('%d')
    # >>>20

    usr_calendar = calendar.monthcalendar(int(year), int(month))
    #[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17], [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24], [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]]
    current_week = []

    for day in usr_calendar:
        print(day)
        # >>>[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
            #[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
            #[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
            #[18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
            #[25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]

        if current_day in day:
            current_week.append(day)

    print(current_week)
    # >>> []

get_week()
```

Пытаюсь получить точную неделю, в зависимости от того, какой сегодня день. Но на выходе выдает пустой список. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Ну так `current_day` это строка же

Comment: @andreymal добавил int(current_day) - сработало. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @MilkiweedGtlt код всё равно дико сложный какой-то, раза в два упростить точно можно (а скорее всего и раз в пять можно, но я не настолько крут)

Comment: @andreymal на быструю руку делалось) да и в целом моего опыта мало чтоб крутой код писать ;D

Comment: Если цель — только получить текущую неделю и всё, то как минимум вот так сокращается https://pastebin.com/yxDD8r0m

Comment: @andreymal бооольшое спасибо))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from calendar import monthcalendar 

def weekcalendar(date):
    return next(week for week in monthcalendar(date.year, date.month) if date.day in week)
```

Пример:

```
>>> import datetime as DT
>>> weekcalendar(DT.date.today())
[18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
```